# unable to connect to hdfs on localhost

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am unable to connect to hdfs on port 9000, I keep getting this error:

```
localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

hdfs-site.xml file is this:

```
<configuration>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
     </property>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>file:/usr/local/hdfs/namenode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>file:/usr/localhdfs/datanode</value>
     </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
        <value>true</value>
     </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
     <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-bind-host</name>
        <value>0.0.0.0</value>
     </property>
</configuration>
```

and core-site.xml file is this:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

I have restarted the cluster multiple times, I keep getting connection errors:

this is my /etc/hosts file look like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

what am I missing?

Comment: What are your proxy settings? Are you using Ranger?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where are you trying to connect **from**? Using what tools? Because it's there that you're missing a port value, and the default 8020 is being used meanwhile HDFS is on 9000 apparently

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using port 9000 in your config? `fs.defaultFS` should contain something like: `hdfs://nameofcluster`
Is this a single node instance? Sandbox? Are you running the command `hdfs dfs -ls /`?

I would first check:

- Remove port from `fs.default.name`
- iptables or Firewalls
- `hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts`
- `hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups`
- Ranger
- Logs are exceeding 80% of disk

Comment: `nameofcluster` implies a name service is being used. It appears this configuration was attempted, which uses port 9000... Also Ranger?? The HDP sandbox isn't used here http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation

Answer (score 0):

1. `/etc/hosts` file contains the FQDN and your machine's public IP.
   Get the IP with `ip a` command and set is like: `192.166.6.6 abc.xxx.com`
2. Delete `fs.default.name` property from `hdfs-site.xml`

[Configure a Single node cluster](https://www.tecmint.com/install-configure-apache-hadoop-centos-7/)

Comment: I don't think "TecMint" is the "right doc"... First would be the Apache site, followed by Hortonworks/Cloudera

Comment: Also, port 9000 is the new default http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#Pseudo-Distributed_Operation

Comment: @cricket_007 Indeed. But for someone not so experienced it is easy to follow this document. That's why I gave this link.

Comment: Perhaps. I wish there were more documents that used Ambari to do automated installs of BigTop or HDP distribution :(

Comment: @cricket_007 Hah! True. We're creating an automated script for the same. :)